# bash: How to warp interpolated variable in quotes to pass it (together with quotes) as argument to another command in script

Tags: bash

So simple, but I am completely stuck.

I need to warp some variable content in quotes and pass it to another command with those quotes.

So I need to run the command

```
docker run -e "VAR=val" ...
```

where `VAR=val` is content of variable `env`. So I try this

```
env="VAR=val"
set -x
docker run -e \"$env\" some_image
```

but when interpolating bash adds another single quotes around!  The output is:

```
docker run -e '"VAR=val"' ...
```

How to strip those single quotes? And leave only double quotes?

If I do

```
docker run -e \'$env\' some_image
```

the result makes me crazy at all

```
docker run -e ''\''VAR=val'\''' ...
```

I can't get the logic here, please help!

Comment: The double quotes around `"VAR=val"` are removed by the shell. `docker run -e "$env" ...` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument that the `docker` binary sees will contain only the double quotes.

The single quotes are added by the `set -x` mechanism only for the purpose of *showing you* what is in the argument list.

---

I suspect you don't actually want `docker` to see *any* of the quotes. In that case, don't escape them in your command, and instead do

```
docker run -e "$env" some_image
```

Double quotes in that position means that if the value of `$env` contains spaces, it will still be passed to `docker` as a *single* argument (with spaces in it), rather than being split into several argument (which would confuse it).

These two commands will produce exactly the same argument array in the new process:

```
docker run -e VAR=val some_image
docker run -e "VAR=val" some_image
```

In the second of these cases the double quotes are interpreted by the shell (even though they are not necessary because the argument doesn't contain spaces), and what `docker` sees in both cases is just the string `VAR=val`.

If you try something like

```
env="VAR=multiple words"
set +x
docker run -r "$env" some_image
```

the third command-line argument to `docker` will be the spaceful string `VAR=multiple words`, and this get printed by `set -x` as something like

```
+ docker run -r 'VAR=multiple words' some_image
```

because the print-the-command-line-before-executing code can see it would be confusing *not* to quote this spaceful string. Again the `docker` command doesn't see any quotes at all in this invocation.

---

For debugging these things it can be useful to replace the actual command you're starting with `echo`. This will print the raw arguments the command sees, without adding any quoting of its own. The downside of this is that you won't be able to tell the difference between a space that is *part of* a single argument and the space that `echo` prints by itself *between* the arguments.